# What is a Prepositional complement?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Could someone tell me what Prepositional complement is? 
The text that brought this issue up says:

> ... a possessive is used as Prepositional complement.

They give an example:

- what business is it of hers?

So is anybody able to explain what a "Prepositional complement" is in English grammar?

Comment: Please quote what your 'text' says. Otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually its kind of written like this :

Comment: Possessives as pronouns :

Comment: A possessive as Prepositional complement - example :what business is it of hers?

Comment: My teacher dictated the notes like this. Its not actually from text.. But I can't understand what Prepositional complement is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What business is it **of hers**?

Sentences can be broken into Phrases. For example we have Noun Phrases, Verb Phrases, Adjective Phrases and so forth. Inside bigger phrases, we have smaller phrases. So, for example, we can break down the following sentence into different phrases:

1. I usually eat square biscuits from France
2. usually eat square biscuits from France
3. square biscuits from France
4. from France

The first example here is a special phrase called a sentence/clause. (2) is a Verb Phrase. Inside (2), we find (3) which is a Noun Phrase. (4) is a Prepositional Phrase.

The main grammatical word in each phrase is the *head* of the phrase. The head of the Verb phrase is the Verb, the head of the Noun phrase is the Noun. The head of the Preposition Phrase is a Preposition. Specifically the head of *from France* is the Preposition *from*. The main word there is *from*, not *France*.

Prepositions usually are followed by a Noun. In example (4), we see the preposition *from* followed by the Noun *France*. The complement of a preposition is the other words that belong to that preposition. So in "at the window", the complement of the preposition *at* is *the window*. In "from France", the complement of *from* is *France*. In the Original Poster's example the possessive *hers* is the complement of *of* in "of hers".

A *Prepositional complement* is another way of saying *the complement of a preposition*.

[It is a very unhelpful term though, because it could have two meanings ...

- the complement of a Preposition

... or:

- a complement which *is* a Preposition.

So, my advice is not to use this term yourself in your writing.]

Answer (score 0):

In grammars you won't find something like a friend of mine/of yours etc under prepositions. It should be dealth with in the chapter Possessive adjectives and pronouns, but mostly you find it in the chapter genitive as double genitive.